# Separate LAMP in 2 servers

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I wanna isntall apache + php in a server and my sql in another server
How can they communicate ?
What should i install in both servers and what should i do to let them communicate so the web application can acccess to the data base (mySQL)in the other server ?

Answer (score 0):

On server 1: `MySQL` (server)

On server 2: `Apache + Php + Mysqlclient` (to communicate with server 1)

Answer (score 0):

On `web-server (192.168.10.11)` Install `Apache + PHP`

On `db-server (192.168.10.12)` Install `MySQL`

- The IPs are for example.

Also You have to doing these steps on `db-server`:

1. Edit `bind-address` in `my.cnf` (`MySQL` configuration):

```
bind-address = 192.168.10.12
```

2. Create `web_user` who access to `mysql` on `bind-address`:

```
CREATE USER 'web_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'web_password';
CREATE USER 'web_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'web_password'

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'web_user'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'web_user'@'%';

flush privileges;
```

3. Depending on your OS you may have to open port `3306` on `db-server` to allow external connection.